# glm::perspective function's near plane and far plane and aspect ratio

Tags: perspective, projection-matrix

two questions but the first one is, in the learnopengl.com website, for the `glm::perspective` function, it tells me to input 0.1f for the near plane, and 100.0f for the far plane. Why do I supply positive numbers. Isn't OpenGL using a right handed coordinate system so the negative z axis is forward so shouldn't the near and far plane both be negative numbers (-0.1f and -100.0f)?

Second question is, what is the aspect ratio in the `glm::perspection` function for? Is it for sizing the near and far planes? Depending on how big the screen is, it's going to make the near and far planes the same ratio?